# Refresh parent with tab on close

Tags: javascript

I have a page with multiple tabs referenced in the div id:

```
<div id="tabs-notes">
```

A couple of these tabs have links to a popup javascript window like so:

```
<input type="button" value="Edit some things" onClick="javascript:openDialog('editSomeThings.html','Edit some things','900','600');" />
```

I would like to have the parent page refresh on close and return to the tab the user left. I have used the following script on other pages but this refreshes the parent returning the user to the first tab not the one they left.

Is there a way to use similar and have the page refresh and return to the tab the user was on when they opened the popup?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, open: '', height: '100', width: '100', resizable: true, title: '', close: function() {
     window.location.reload();
 } });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what behavior you want, but perhaps `window.parent` is what you want? E.g. `window.parent.location.reload()`?

Comment: You could first set `window.location.hash` (or perhaps `window.parent.location.hash`, depending on where you're doing it) to `"#tabs-notes"`.

Comment: After further reading I think you are correct this would be the way to do it but my issue now is the #tabs-notes anchor isn't in the URL when you navigate on the parent page. window.part.location.reload() is working as intended but since the parent is www.abc.com/index.html not www.abc.com/index.html#tabs-notes you land back at the first tab.